# What's wrong with this query?

Tags: python, mysql

I'm trying to execute the following in my function but I'm getting an error
`You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '/ (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE registered_at BETWEEN '1293861600' AND '1303' at line 1")`

I'm basically trying to divide the first SELECT statement with the second SELECT statement.

```
cursor.execute( "(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE "
                    "       (registered_at BETWEEN '1293861600' AND '1303729537') "
                    "                   AND user_id IN (    SELECT parent_id FROM files "
                    "                                       WHERE created_at > '1293861600')) / "
                    "(SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users " 
                    "WHERE registered_at BETWEEN '1293861600' AND '1303729537') " )
```

Also, is there a better way of re-writing this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
cursor.execute( "SELECT COUNT(1) "
                " / ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users " 
                "     WHERE registered_at BETWEEN '1293861600' AND '1303729537') " 
                " FROM users "
                " WHERE ( registered_at BETWEEN '1293861600' AND '1303729537') "
                "   AND user_id IN ( SELECT parent_id FROM files "
                "                    WHERE created_at > '1293861600') " )
```

The **IN** could be changed into **JOIN**:

```
cursor.execute( " SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT users.user_id) "
                "        / ( SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users " 
                "            WHERE registered_at "
                "              BETWEEN '1293861600' AND '1303729537') " 
                " FROM users "
                "   JOIN files "
                "     ON files.parent_id = users.user_id "
                " WHERE ( users.registered_at BETWEEN '1293861600' AND '1303729537') "
                "   AND ( files.created_at > '1293861600') "
              )
```

The query could also be rewritten using one subquery, like this:

```
cursor.execute( " SELECT SUM(IF(user_id IN ( SELECT parent_id "
                "                            FROM files "
                "                            WHERE created_at > '1293861600') "
                "              ,1 ,0 ) ) "
                "        / COUNT(1) "
                " FROM users "
                " WHERE users.registered_at BETWEEN '1293861600' AND '1303729537' "
              )
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably need to prepend `SELECT` to your query.

Answer (score 1):

You need a select before the whole thing, thus:

```
cursor.execute( "select (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE " ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Execute below query to see what you want..

SELECT (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE registered_at BETWEEN 1293861600 AND 1303729537 AND user_id IN ( SELECT parent_id FROM files WHERE created_at > 1293861600)) / (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM users WHERE registered_at BETWEEN 1293861600 AND 1303729537) As Results

The above division will only work if you get only one result in both the select statements.